# jQuery togle “active” class between X number of buttons while adding/removing unique classnames

Tags: html, jquery, css, button

I have **unknown number** of buttons for e.g lets say I got 3. Here how my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="my-lovely-buttons">
    <button class="btn-one">1</button>
    <button class="btn-two">2</button>
    ...
    <button class="btn-twentytwo">22</button>
</div>

<div class="awesome-element"></div>
```

**Using jQuery I need them to have these conditions:**

1. By default none of buttons have class "active"
2. When you press respective  you can toggleClass("active")
3. If I press any of them, and one already has class "active" it needs to remove from the sibling  and add it the one I just pressed.
4. Upon pressing one of the buttons, they would toggle another classes for "awesome-element". (please see jQuery code in example below)
5. If I press for e.g "btn-one" (which added classes for "awesome-element") and then immediately press "btn-two" it needs to remove added classes by "btn-one" and toggle respective classes from "btn-two" (cause "btn-two" now has class "active" and "btn-one" does not. See my jQuery code below)

**So my jQuery looked like this:**

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#my-lovely-buttons', function () {
        $(".btn-one").toggleClass("active");
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("hidden shown");
    });
});


$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#my-lovely-buttons', function () {
        $(".btn-two").toggleClass("active");
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("big small");
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#my-lovely-buttons', function () {
        $(".btn-twentytwo").toggleClass("active");
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("selected");
    });
});
```

As you can see, this code above does not solve **condition number "3"** as it just toggle "active" class without removing it from the sibling. Also, it does not solve **condition number "5"**. And overall I think it can be written better, maybe within 1 function instead of making a function for every button like I have in my code. I am really new to jQuery, please don't judge.

```js
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#my-lovely-buttons', function () {
        $(".btn-one").toggleClass("active");
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("hidden shown");
    });
});


$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#my-lovely-buttons', function () {
        $(".btn-two").toggleClass("active");
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("big small");
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#my-lovely-buttons', function () {
        $(".btn-twentytwo").toggleClass("active");
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("selected");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-lovely-buttons">
    <button class="btn-one">1</button>
    <button class="btn-two">2</button>
    ...
    <button class="btn-twentytwo">22</button>
</div>

<div class="awesome-element"></div>
```

Comment: _"unique classnames"_ is a (imho big) code smell...

Comment: Common pattern: `$("#my-lovely-buttons").on("click", "button", function() { $(".active").removeClass("active"); $(this).addClass("active") });` - no need for any classes.

Comment: The requirement for when/why `.awesome-element` should toggle and which classes it toggles when (etc) is just unclear.

Comment: You can see that from jQuery code below. For e.g If I press `btn-one` it toggles `("hidden shown")` and if i press `btn-two` it should remove previously added classes `hidden or shown` and add/toggle `("big small")`;

Comment: Also `$("#my-lovely-buttons").on("click", "button", function() { $(".active").removeClass("active"); $(this).addClass("active") });` this code does not togle ".active" class it only removes from one button and adds to another, but i cant remove it by pressing on the button.

Comment: This code worked for me: 
`$("#my-lovely-buttons").on("click", "button", function() {
    $('button').not(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});`

but now i need help with the condition number 4 and 5 :(

Comment: If you make `.awesome-element` an ID, you can clear the `className` attribute entirely and re-set it to whatever you like: `$('#awesome-element').get(0).className = newClassName`